# All sites themes functions.php have been changed

Tags: plugins, php, functions, themes

all of the themes functions.php have been changed for the sites on my web hosting server.

Because I couldn't copy it here without making it look ok, the code is here:
https://justpaste.it/18emu

Is this legit? The core functions.php doesn't have it.
Can plugins make changes to the files outside their currently directory? For example, can the plugins of site A make changes to the site B, even though they are not in the same directory?

Also, a "datalist" table has been added to their database.

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Check out this link, it seems you are not the only one with the issue and there appears to be a solution. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/code-injected-in-theme-functions-php-table-added/